# Python Polars - add element to columns of lists which has value equal to a function of the list

Tags: python, python-polars

if I have a columns of lists, for example:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'lists': [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]]})
```

And I want to add max(list)+2 to each list as an additional element, to get:

```
expected_df = pl.DataFrame({'lists': [[1,2,3,5], [2,3,4,6], [3,4,5,7]]})
```

How do I do this in polars?

I'd have thought it would be something like:

```
expected_df.with_columns(pl.col('lists').arr.add_element(pl.col('lists').arr.max()+2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```py
>>> df.with_columns(pl.col('lists').list.concat(pl.col('lists').list.max() + 2))
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────────┐
│ lists       │
│ ---         │
│ list[i64]   │
╞═════════════╡
│ [1, 2, … 5] │
│ [2, 3, … 6] │
│ [3, 4, … 7] │
└─────────────
```

Let's make sure that the expected result is obtained:

```py
>>> expected_df = pl.DataFrame({'lists': [[1,2,3,5], [2,3,4,6], [3,4,5,7]]})
>>> df.with_columns(pl.col('lists').list.concat(pl.col('lists').list.max() + 2)).frame_equal(expected_df)
True
```